# Retrieving a provisioning script by name

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to retrieve a provisioning script entry by name. The URL I am using is `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getPostProvisioningHooks.json?objectMask=mask[hookType]&objectFilter={"provisioninghook":{"name":{"operation":"^=Windows-MEL01"}}}`

I have tried using provisioninghook, hook, and postprovisioninghook before the name specification. None of tehm work, it still returns all the provision hook entries. Hoe do I specify the objectFilter for searching by provisioning hook name?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getPostProvisioningHooks?objectMask=mask[hookType]&objectFilter={"postProvisioningHooks":{"name":{"operation":"Windows-MEL01"}}}

Method: Get
```

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Account::getPostProvisioningHooks](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPostProvisioningHooks)
- [Object Filters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters)

Comment: Thank you.  I see that it is case sensitive.